# How to sum elements of two multidimensional arrays?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

I have 2 multidimensional arrays:

```
[[230.0], [10.0], [12.0]]

[[50.0], [60.0], [89.0]]
```

And am trying to sum each element together and keep the same array structure. So it should look like:

```
[[280.0], [70.0], [101.0]]
```

I tried this:

```
 var sum = array1.map(function (num, index) {
  return num + array2[index];
   });
```

But I get this:

```
    [23050, 1060, 1289]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it like this

```
var sum = array1.map(function (num, index) {
  return parseInt(num) + parseInt(array2[index]);
   });
```

You should have to make `parseInt` or `parseFloat` so it can convert `string` with them

Comment: This is solving the side effect of trying to add two arrays, this doesnt actually address the issue.

Comment: He is adding two arrays of integers [1] + [1] which then the JS engine interprets as "1" + "1" in my opinion this is solving the side effect of this. The best solution would be the flatten the inner arrays and then perform a simple addition of the 2 integers.

Answer (score 1):

The code, you use, takes only a single level, without respecting nested arrays. By taking na array with only one element without an index of the inner array and using an operator, like `+`, the prototype function `toString` is invoced and a joined string (the single element as string, without `,` as separator) is returned and added. The result is a string , not the result of a numerical operation with `+`.

---

You could take a recursive approach and check if the value is an array, then call the function again with the nested element.

```js
function sum(a, b) {
    return a.map((v, i) => Array.isArray(v) ? sum(v, b[i]) : v + b[i]);
}

console.log(sum([[230], [10], [12]], [[50], [60], [89]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

**STEPS**

1. Iterate through every number in the array (array length).
2. Sum the objects of the same index in both of the arrays.
3. Push the sum into another array for the result. Use parseFloat if the input is string.
4. (Optional) use .toFixed(1) to set decimal place to have 1 digit.

```js
const arr1 = [[230.0], [10.0], [12.0]]
const arr2 = [[50.0], [60.0], [89.0]]

let sum = []
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){ // Assume arr1 and arr2 have the same size
  let eachSum = parseFloat(arr1[i]) + parseFloat(arr2[i])
  sum.push([eachSum.toFixed(1)])
}

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add two arrays structures inside the map function.

so one solution so you can see what is happening is this...

```
array1.map((a,i) => a[0] + array2[i][0])
```

screenshot from the console...

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Inside map fn you should:

```
return parseInt(num) + parseInt(array2[index]);
```

This is happening because when you are trying to add them, these variable are arrays and not integers. So they are evaluated as strings and concatenated.